# Cannot access empty property on entity.inc line 277 when trying to access entity add page

Tags: 7, entities

I created a new entity type with hook_entity_info using this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info().
 */
function custom_payment_entity_info() {
    return array(
        'custom_payment_period' => array(
            'label' => t('Period'),
            'plural label' => t('Periods'),
            'entity class' => 'Entity',
            'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
            'base table' => 'custom_payment_periods',
            'revision table' => 'custom_payment_period_revisions',
            'entity keys' => array(
                'id' => 'pid',
                'revision' => 'pvid',
            ),
            'fieldable' => TRUE,
            'static cache' => FALSE,
            'label callback' => 'entity_class_label',
            'uri callback' => 'entity_class_uri',
            'access callback' => 'custom_payment_access',
            'module' => 'custom_payment',
            'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
            'admin ui' => array(
                'path' => 'admin/config/custom/custom-payment',
                'file' => '/forms/custom_payment.period.form.inc',
                'controller class' => 'EntityDefaultUIController',
                'menu wildcard' => '%period',
            ),
            'bundles' => array(
                'period' => array(
                    'label' => t('Period'),
                    'admin' => array(
                        'path' => 'admin/config/custom/custom-payment',
                        'access arguments' => array('administrator custom payment periods'),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But when i try to create new entity through the admin add page i get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\sfn\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.inc on
>   line 277

This is the form function:

```
function custom_payment_period_form($form, &$form_state, $period = NULL) {
    $form['period'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Period'),
        '#size' => 5,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'),
        '#default_value' => isset($period->period) ? $period->period : ''
    );
    $form['type'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Period Type'),
        '#options' => array(
            1 => t('Day'),
            2 => t('Month'),
            3 => t('Year')
        ),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => isset($period->type) ? $period->type : ''
    );
    $form['price'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Price'),
        '#size' => 5,
        '#field_suffix' => t('SYP'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'),
        '#default_value' => isset($period->price) ? $period->price : ''
    );
    $form['weight'] = array(
        '#type' => 'weight',
        '#title' => t('Position'),
        '#default_value' => isset($period->weight) ? $period->weight : ''
    );
    field_attach_form('period', $period, $form, $form_state);
    $form['actions'] = array(
        '#type' => 'actions',
        'submit' => array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Save')
        )
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Can you help me fix this?

---

It's my first time working with entity type creation i followed the entity API documentation and the video entity example found here github.com/Lullabot/entity-api-demos/tree/master/docroot/sit‌​es/… i don't know exactly what is messing here.

Comment: Do you have an entity create function, and/or a menu loader function for like `'menu wildcard' => '%period',`. I dont really see where you're creating an empty Entity in your code for the form to use.

Comment: @tenken it's my first time working with entity type creation i followed the entity api documenation and the video entity example found here https://github.com/Lullabot/entity-api-demos/tree/master/docroot/sites/all/modules/custom/videoentity i don't know exaactly what is messing here

Comment: Your entity keys don't seem to include bundle, label, or language.

Comment: @tenken the problem was in two things: i had to add a label entity key to fix this error and then i had to remove the `'menu wildcard' => '%period'` from the admin ui array because i got an error on edit page because of it and everything worked then as expected but is there a way to create an entity type without a `"label"` entity key?

Answer (score 0):

Your entity keys don't seem to include bundle, label, or language. - [@beth](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130086/cannot-access-empty-property-on-entity-inc-line-277-when-trying-to-access-entity#comment156042_130086)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in two things:

- I had to add a label entity key to fix this error
- I had to remove the `'menu wildcard' => '%period'` from the admin UI array,

because I got an error on edit page because of it and everything worked then as expected. It seems there was a problem creating an entity type without a "label" entity key.

<sup>Source: [OP comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130086/cannot-access-empty-property-on-entity-inc-line-277-when-trying-to-access-entity/215033#comment156436_130086).</sup>